# sudo not working after chmod -R 777 /bin at wrong location

Tags: linux, sudo, root, chmod

By mistake i executed below command

```
[root@ip-172-31-71-252 ~]# chmod -R 777 /bin
```

and location was

```
[root@ip-172-31-71-252 ~]# pwd
/root
```

Then I logged out of from root session and tried 'sudo -i' I am getting below error

sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set

I am not able run any command using sudo.

How to solve this?

Comment: I see you are using root, so you could use `chmod 4755 /bin/sudo` to fix sudo.
You can also try `chmod -R 4755 /bin` for fixing all perms in `/bin`.

Comment: About `chmod -R 4755 /bin` might have problems because a few files have different  permissions: `rwsr-xr-x` or `rwxrwxr-x`, `rwxr-x---`, etc.

Comment: OP's command removed any "power" to available suid root commands in /bin/ (<=> on recent linux  /usr/bin/) like su, sudo, pkexec ... Unless a suitable command exists in /sbin/ or /usr/local/*bin/ looks like it's rescue live boot time... Sometimes the "security" of having root without password and login becomes a problem.